# How to add parameters in rest api for specific response in code?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, parameters

I have created my very first basic rest api. Its working find and give me output in xml using this url

```
http://localhost:8080/Webservice/Test/RestClient
```

Now, I'm thinking If I want my api to ask server only specific data then I how can I use parameters for the same in api url.

Here is my little updated code

```
package RestClient;

//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Path("/RestClient")
@XmlRootElement
public class Restwebclient {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello(@PathParam("x") int x, @PathParam("y") int y) {

        String output = "";

        if (x == 1 && y == 1) {
            output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
        }

        else if (x == 2 && y == 2) {
            output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
        }

        return output;
    }

}
```

And web.xml is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Webservice</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>RestClient</param-value>
</init-param>   
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

But when run the url passing parameters like this nothing comes up in output

```
http://localhost:8080/Webservice/Test/RestClient?x=1&y=1
```

Note: Expected output from above parameters in url should be first if condition

May I know What I'm missing to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending parameters in query so you should use `@QueryParam` and not `@PathParam`. change method to:

```
public String sayXMLHello(@QueryParam("x") int x, @QueryParam("y") int y) {
```

Query Params:

```
http://localhost:8080/Webservice/Test/RestClient?x=1&y=1
```

Path Params need to change Path:

```
@Path("{x}/{y}/RestClient")

http://localhost:8080/Webservice/Test/1/1/RestClient
```

Comment: Add when we use PathParam ?

Comment: add details to path parameters

Comment: Please share with me one thing.I want to authenticate user and provide token for accessing web server. Do I really need to use OAuth concept.Cant't I make it mine, I mean first url will be having username, password and master token.This request will return me token to access web server data. In web server side I would like to create two methods first will authenticate user, password and master token and in second method which will expose data if generated token matches with generated from first method.I can also generate expiry time and store somewhere to match expiry with token Is make sense?

Comment: sorry but please ask a new question

Comment: Please check this question..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141176/restapi-authentication-without-oauth-library