# restapi authentication without OAuth library

Tags: java, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have working REST API and would like to authenticate users by providing tokens with expiry dates but without using OAuth library.

Here is what I'm thinking.

Can I create two methods, first will be having three parameters

```
Username, Password and Master token
```

And once its authenticate, it will produce one temporary token with some expiry date. This I will store into in database entry and will return to the client as well.

So when I will make second request with URL having token generated by first method, it will check into second method having parameter "token" where it will match with database entry, and if it agrees data will be exposed.

Can I do it in that way ? Does it makes sense for having authentication in this way ? If no please share your comments.

Comment: You can and companies uses such mechanism. oath should be done when it's requested/needed specifically

Comment: OAuth is NOT for Authentication but for Authorization. If you require Authentication you should use an OpenID Connect and an approved library. (https://openid.net/developers/libraries/ )  Using a "roll-your-own" method is not recommended.